# MySQL - Using a date range vs functions

Tags: mysql, date, date-range

I needed to know how many users registered during June and July, this is the first query I wrote:

```
select count(*) from users where created_at>="2013-06-01" and created_at<="2013-07-31"
```

Result: 15,982

```
select count(*) from users where year(created_at)=2013 and month(created_at) in (6,7)
```

Result: 16,278

Why do they return a different result? Could someone explain? Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of the created_at column?  If it happens to be a char based column instead of a date column it may not compare as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Both query should be equivalent, except that the first one is able to make use of an index and it should be faster, and except the case in which `created_at` is not a DATE but is a TIMESTAMP.

If `created_at` is a timestamp, you should write your first query this way:

```
select count(*) from users
where created_at>='2013-06-01' and created_at<'2013-08-01'
```

otherwise your first query will exclude all records created on 31th of July, after midnight, eg. `2013-07-31 00:00:00` will be included while `2013-07-31 09:15:43` will be not.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your date values do not include the last day: The date constants are converted to a timestamp at midnight. You are querying between these values:

```
2013-06-01 00:00:00
2013-07-31 00:00:00
```

So only the first second of the last day is included.

Try this:

```
select count(*)
from users
where created_at>="2013-06-01"
and created_at<="2013-07-31 23:59:59"
```

Or more simply make *less than* the *next* day:

```
select count(*)
from users
where created_at>="2013-06-01"
and created_at<"2013-08-01" -- < 1st day of next month
```